# GoogleMaps: default streetview image in custom InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps

When I use Google Maps as an anonymous user, when I find a company that I'm building a website for, Google shows me some kind of a default street view photo for that place. It's quite nice and I would like to have this photo appear also in my custom InfoWindow that I'm preparing using API3. Is there a method for that or should I sniff and use its source path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the street view panorama like this, or embed a screen capture image in the infowindow contents (`<img src="...">`)  Also you may set the marker `visible: false`

http://jsfiddle.net/sST8z/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
      #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 500px; height: 300px }
      #street { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 150px; height: 150px }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        street = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("street"), { 

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.72982797782924, -73.98622512817383),
        zoomControl: false,
        enableCloseButton: false,
        addressControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        linksControl: false
      });


      var infow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: document.getElementById("street") });
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.72982797782924, -73.98622512817383);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map, visible: true });

      infow.open(map, marker);
      map.setCenter(myLatLng);

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="street"></div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works in js fiddle, so I'm accepting it, but for some reason (XHTML + gmap document.write?) not on my page. One more related question: when I pan the streetview panorama to position it nicely (as the default is quite random),  is it the possible to capture all the parameters (tilt, azimuth, distance, etc.) and paste them somehow into the javascript code?

Comment: I got it solved: google.maps.event.addListener(street , 'pov_changed', function() {console.log(street.pov)});

Comment: Looks however like it's not possible to have both panorama and text content in info window. Any concatenation of .innerHTML and text produced bogus results.

Comment: Are you trying something complex? I'm able to get some words and a image together with the street view http://jsfiddle.net/sST8z/2/ Just wrap the street view with another div `<div id="textwrapper"><div id="street"></div>Cool stairs</div>` and place the new div, `textwrapper` in the infowindow contents.

Comment: Darn. I haven't tried that. And in fact I took a wrong approach, putting the markup as the InfoWindow contents upon creation. Will try to prepare the containers in HTML so it's ready right away. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm now :) Thanks. Brrr-meow.